# Filter out link address from DOM results

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm working with a DOM parser that grabs links from a website by the class thumbnail. This returns a list of links. They are then converted to their image state and shown on the page. The problem I'm having is I have 2 different links that are getting returned:

http://i.imgur.com/randomstuffhere
AND
http://imgur.com/randomstuffhere

I need to filter the results for the links that DO NOT contain the i.imgur.com. If the link is a imgur link but does not contain the i. before I need to filter it out not to show.
I have this so far and I cannot figure out where I've gone wrong... Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.reddit.com/r/funny');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hyperlinks = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="thumbnail "]');

foreach($hyperlinks as $hyperlink) {
 if (preg_match("/http://imgur.com/", $hyperlink->getAttribute('href'))){
  }
  else{
       echo "<img style='padding-left:30%' width=\"500\" src=\"" . $hyperlink->getAttribute('href') . "\" alt=\"\" />";
  echo "<br />";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `preg_match` is total overkill for this task. Use `strpos` instead

Comment: "If the link is a imgur link but does not contain the i. before I need to filter it out not to show" - do you need to filter "imgur.com" links without i or don't you need to do it?

Comment: I need to filter the links without the i. beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `//` in `http://` with `\/\/`.

You should probably use `strpos`, though.

```
if(strpos($hyperlink->getAttribute('href'), 'http://i.imgur.com/') !== FALSE){
  echo "This is an i.imgur.com link!";
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! Sorry for the comment before about it not working. I didn't check the edit... Stupid me!

Comment: Note, you can use a different regex delimiter (`@` is a popular choice) if you want to avoid escaping a bunch of forward-slashes

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The argument order always gets me in PHP.